# Static security mapping using spring-security-core on grails 2.4.3

Tags: grails, spring-security

Using spring-security-core (2.0-RC4) i am having problems with static security mapping.

```
'/app/client/**':                  ['IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY'],  
'/app/items/**':                   ['permitAll'],
```

and this configuration (or even switching the true/false values)

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rejectIfNoRule = true
grails.plugin.springsecurity.fii.rejectPublicInvocations = false
```

When i try to access

```
/app/items/Books
```

I get 403/500 (depending on configuration parameters). The only way i can access is when both configuration properties are false so i end with optimistic approach which i intend to avoid.

Is there something bad with the pattern?
Can comeone gives some light on what can be happening in the hoods?

Thanks,

UPDATE:

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.login.active = true
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.token.storage.useGorm = true
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.token.storage.gorm.tokenDomainClassName = 'com.moviesxd.api.domain.AuthenticationToken'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.token.storage.gorm.tokenValuePropertyName = 'tokenValue'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.token.storage.gorm.usernamePropertyName = 'username'

grails.plugin.springsecurity.securityConfigType = "Annotation"

grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.token.validation.enableAnonymousAccess = true

//Workaround for weird responses when using a bearer token
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.token.validation.useBearerToken = false

grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.login.active = true
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.login.endpointUrl = '/security/login'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.logout.endpointUrl = '/security/logout'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.login.failureStatusCode = 401
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.login.useJsonCredentials = true
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.login.usernamePropertyName = 'username'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.login.passwordPropertyName = 'password'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.token.validation.headerName = 'X-Auth-Token'
```

UPDATE:

```
'/':                                ['permitAll'],
'/index':                           ['permitAll'],
'/index.gsp':                       ['permitAll'],
'/assets/**':                       ['permitAll'],
'/**/js/**':                        ['permitAll'],
'/**/css/**':                       ['permitAll'],
'/**/images/**':                    ['permitAll'],
'/**/favicon.ico':                  ['permitAll'],
```

Comment: It seems like the pattern is not mathced since it behaves like triggering the "ifNoRule" constrain ... but don't understand why.

Comment: The pattern should not include the name of your application. E.g. `/clients/**` and `/items/**`

Comment: app is not the name of my application ... is just something i want to organize my API calls

Comment: Okay, just a common mistake made. Also, it's best if you include all of your security configuration in your question.

Comment: Is there a good way to debug this to understand why is this not matching as i expect?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `rejectIfNoRule` property set to true, you have unknowingly blocked the access on root url i.e. at **/**. So allow that rule by modifying your rules like this:

```
'/':                               ['permitAll'],
'/index':                          ['permitAll'],
'/index.gsp':                      ['permitAll'],
'/app/client/**':                  ['IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY'],  
'/app/items/**':                   ['permitAll']
```

Read [here](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/guide/single.html#requestMappings) for more info.
Hope this helps!

Thanks,
SA

Comment: Thanks SA ... however i've already declared those resources as permitAll. I've placed an update in the question text.

Comment: Okay, is your / mapped to index.gsp or to something else? Or are you able to access your root URL?